# How can we search a phrase in pdf and get its coordinates by using PHP

Tags: php, ajax

We have a PDF. We want to search a phrase in that PDF and get its coordinates, with the phrase height and width, all this has to be done programmatically by using PHP.

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what library did you use in reading a PDF file?

Comment: Hi Adhan, We used pdf 2 text function to get the text. But now we require to check whether the specific phrase is present in pdf or not, and if yes we need to highlight that particular text. Kindly suggest.